# Rx DragBehavior -> Why is my Element not moving

Tags: wpf, mvvm, system.reactive

I wrote a DragBehavior based on the general Drag and Drop examples. While this is working without being in a Behavior, it is not moving when I place the code in a behavior.

**Behavior:**

```
public class DragBehavior : Behavior<UIElement>
    {

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            Window mainCanvas = Application.Current.MainWindow;

            var mouseDown = from evt in AssociatedObject.GetMouseLeftButtonDown()
                                select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
            var mouseUp = from evt in AssociatedObject.GetMouseLeftButtonUp()
                            select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
            var mouseMove = from evt in AssociatedObject.GetMouseMove()
                            select evt.EventArgs.GetPosition(mainCanvas);

            var q = from start in mouseDown
                    from delta in mouseMove.StartWith(start).TakeUntil(mouseUp)
                    .Let(mm => mm.Zip(mm.Skip(1),(pre,cur) =>
                        new{ X= cur.X - pre.X, Y= cur.Y - pre.Y}))
                        select delta;

            q.Subscribe(value =>
            {
                Canvas.SetLeft(AssociatedObject, Canvas.GetLeft(AssociatedObject) + value.X);
                Canvas.SetTop(AssociatedObject, Canvas.GetTop(AssociatedObject) + value.Y);
            });

        }
    }
```

**Helper Methods:**

```
  public static IObservable<IEvent<MouseEventArgs>>  GetMouseMove(
             this UIElement inputElement)
        {

            return Observable.FromEvent(
                (EventHandler<MouseEventArgs> h) => new MouseEventHandler(h),
                h => inputElement.MouseMove += h,
                h => inputElement.MouseMove -= h);
        }

        public static IObservable<IEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>>
          GetMouseLeftButtonDown(this UIElement inputElement)
        {
            return Observable.FromEvent(
                (EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> genericHandler) =>
                    new MouseButtonEventHandler(genericHandler),
                            h => inputElement.MouseLeftButtonDown += (h),
                            h => inputElement.MouseLeftButtonDown -= (h));
        }

        public static IObservable<IEvent<MouseButtonEventArgs>>
            GetMouseLeftButtonUp(this UIElement inputElement)
        {
            return Observable.FromEvent(
                (EventHandler<MouseButtonEventArgs> genericHandler) =>
                    new MouseButtonEventHandler(genericHandler),
                            h => inputElement.MouseLeftButtonUp += h,
                            h => inputElement.MouseLeftButtonUp -= h);
        }}


   <Window x:Class="DesignerTest.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DesignerTest.ViewModels"
    xmlns:h="clr-namespace:DesignerTest.Helpers"
    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:WindowViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Shapes}">
     <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <h:DragBehavior />
                    </e:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=X,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=Y,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>  
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your template a little... mb this will help you..

```
<DataTemplate>
    <!-- change background to transparent -->        
    <StackPanel Background="Transparent">            
        <e:Interaction.Behaviors>                        
            <h:DragBehavior />                    
        </e:Interaction.Behaviors> 
        <!-- Prevent yout textBlock from capturing mouse events -->    
        <!-- by setting is HitTestVisible to false -->  
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding X}" IsHitTestVisible="False" />                
    </StackPanel>            
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the code actually running? Add a "When Hit" breakpoint to OnAttached and your Subscribe closure to trace out what's atually happening

Also, a few notes on your implementation:

- I'd recommend creating a `MutableDisposable` private member and assigning the return value of `Subscribe` to it's `Disposable` property. This will allow you to unsubscribe from everything in `OnDetached`
- There's no need to select the MouseUp event's position as `TakeUntil` doesn't require that the sequences be of the same type.

**Edit:** I think the problem is that the `StackPanel` you are adding the Canvas properties to is actually the child of the `ItemContainerTemplate` (`ContentPresenter`) element, not of the `Canvas` itself. You should either walk the tree in the behavior's `OnAttached` method, or define your own `ItemContainerTemplate` and attach the behavior to the `ContentPresenter` instead.

Comment: Code is compiling but not running as expected that's why I was asking. What should I inspect with the breakpoint. The coordinates are actually picked up by the linq2events query result but the element is not moving I am sort of lost ..